# pass character pointer as template type

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class t1,class t2>
class myclass
{
    t1 i;
    t2 j;
    public :
        myclass(t1 x,t2 y)
        {
            i = x;
            j = y;
        }
        void show()
        {
            cout<<"i = "<<i<<" j = "<<j<<endl;
        }
};

main()
{
    myclass<int,double> ob(10,15.2);
    myclass<char,char*>ob1('x',"Template");
    ob.show();
    ob1.show();
}
```

I want to set the type of the second template object to one such that i could pass a character array in the constructor, what type should it be ?

Please See - I use g++ compiler present in GNU GCC compiler set to compile my c++ code.

Comment: If you are working with strings you should be using a `std::string`.

Comment: Since using C++, why not pass std::string? Edit: @NathanOliver was faster. :-)

Comment: yes with string it's possible. I have tried that but is not it possible with character array or character pointer?

Comment: If you want a pointer, you need `const char*`.

Comment: thnx @juanchopanza it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal has a type of `const char(&)[N]`<sup>†</sup>, which can be decayed into `const char*`:

```
myclass<char,const char*>ob1('x',"Template");
```

Also, your `main` should return `int`

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6490d8193701563c)

Also, I feel obligated to repeat what NathanOliver and teroi said in the comments, that you should consider using a `std::string` instead.

<sup>†</sup><sub>It's type is considered "an array of `N` const char" where `N`, is whatever the length of the literal is, Refer to §2.14.5.8 [lex.string]. The `(&)` actually means a reference. String literals have locations in memory, and reusing the same literal will refer to the same memory address (on most compilers, in order to reduce the size of the binary) [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/611991c8ca8c73fd).</sub>

Comment: The first line is incorrect. But a string literal can be assigned to a `const char*`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Revised :-)

Comment: @AndyG yes i got it..yes i do use string in this cases i just wanted to know how that string could be implemented using character pointer and now i got it thnx man...but the main function, it is not mandatory to specify a return type here in c++ when compiling the code with g++ compiler as it automatically sets the return type of main function as integer as far as i know...try it , it won't require return type .

Comment: @Desmond: The standard requires a return type. GCC is being nice to you :-) 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] "An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have
a declared return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined."

Comment: @AndyG oh ok . I understood :)